# Why do I get the same output no matter which paragraph I click on?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign a function on paragraphs using a for loop. I expect the console to show "0" and "1" when I click the paragraphs, but  the actual output is "2".

This is my code:

```js
var para = document.getElementsByName('mypara');
for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
  console.log(i); //this is expected result i.e "0" and "1"
  para[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(i) //here it is printing "2" no matter on which para i click
  });
}
```

```html
<p name="mypara">1</p>
<p name="mypara">2</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to let instead of var (the way to go)

```
<script>
      var para = document.getElementsByName('mypara');
      for (let i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
        console.log(i); //this is expected result i.e "0" and "1"
        para[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log(i) 
        });
      }

</script>
```

Or if you want to keep the var create a closure (avoid it)

```
<script>
  var para = document.getElementsByName('mypara');
  for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
    ((i) => {
      console.log(i); //this is expected result i.e "0" and "1"
      para[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(i) 
      });

    })(i)
  }

</script>
```

Explanation:

This is because, at the point that the click method is invoked  the for loop has already completed and the variable i already has a value of 2,

In order for this to work you need to capture the value of i at each iteration through the for loop by passing it into a newly created function object (closures).

See: execution contexts, variable objects, activation objects, internal scope closures and loops...

As the comment below the answer points out never user var's, **rely on const and let**

Comment: Explain please.

Comment: Thanks! I really don't know what was the problem because I always been used "var" but for this time "let" worked fine.

Comment: Rule of thumb: never use `var` anymore, `const` and `let` are great and have much more straightforward scoping rules

Answer (score 0):

You're logging out whatever the last value of "i" is, passing the event object through and reading the data from it should give you the result you're after.

```js
var para = document.getElementsByName('mypara');
for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
  console.log(i); //this is expected result i.e "0" and "1"
  para[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  });
}
```

```html
<p name="mypara">1</p>
<p name="mypara">2</p>
```